# cgminer works just fine for BTC but LTC mining won't get temps over 50C

Tags: litecoin, miner-configuration, cgminer, gpu-mining

These are the screenshots. Temp on LTC won't go over 50C although I set it to intensity 12 on my 6770. I get 200Mh/s on BTC and I shouuld be getting 200Kh/s, instead I'm getting 80Kh/s.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyUea.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCgsA.jpg

What's going on?

Comment: how old is the gpu? maybe its shot? is it underclocked/overclocked? have you changed the clock settings?

Comment: it's just a few months old, it's an XFX 6770. I had it overclocked at 900 MHz and stock. Both show the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the cgminer.conf for HD6770M I use:

```
"temp-cutoff" : "105",
"temp-target" : "65",
"intensity" : "13",
"vectors" : "1",
"worksize" : "256",
"kernel" : "scrypt",
"scrypt" : true,
"lookup-gap" : "2",
"thread-concurrency" : "3200",
"shaders" : "480",
"gpu-engine" : "815",
"gpu-fan" : "100",
"gpu-memclock" : "919",
"gpu-vddc" : "1.055",
"temp-overheat" : "100",
"gpu-threads" : "1",
"kernel-path" : "C:\\path\\where\\cgminer\\is" (double "\")
```

Hope that helps!